# Incremental refresh for web API in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Is there any possibilities to have incremental refresh for web API (e.g. JIRA APIs)?

I am using web APIs which have data of 10 years. As of now whole data of 10 years is refreshed on each refresh schedule.

Is there anyway I can implement incremental refresh so that:

- only new rows (last update date/time field is available in data source) are added in data set?
- any old rows which are updated (last update date/time field is available in data source) are refreshed in data set?

Note: I am having "Pro Account".

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have DateTime column, then probably it is possible. Create two parameters as described here (You must have exactly this name and datatype):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview#supported-data-sources

Next, check your source statement in M Language (Transformation Data -> Advenced Editor for query); If there is a place with plain date (or somethig which control data range), then you can replace it with parameters.

managed to insert using ""&RangeStart&""